# How to auto select a radio button with PHP on HTML

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I have this code:

```
<tr align="center">
    <td align="center">
        <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="j" value="Pre-Quarantine" checked="<? if ($dato['Status'] == 'Pre-Quaratine'){ echo true; } ?>"/><span>Pre-Quarantine</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="j" value="Quarantine" checked="<? if ($dato['Status'] == 'Quarantine'){ echo true; } ?>"/><span>Quarantine</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="j" value="Released" checked="<? if ($dato['Status'] == 'Released'){ echo true; } ?>"/><span>Released</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I want is to autoselect a radio button based on the value of my database field... But it isn't really working, I would really appreciate if someone could help me :)

Comment: For example `checked="<? if ($dato['Status'] == 'Pre-Quaratine'){ echo true; }` has to be `<? if ($dato['Status'] == 'Pre-Quaratine'){ echo 'checked="checked"'; }`

Comment: @CharlotteDunois    `<input type="radio" name="m" value="Lane" <? if ($dato['Type'] == 'Lane'){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>/> ` LIKE THIS?

Comment: Yes, now you have to do that for every button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The checked attribute causes the element to be checked if it is present. You don't need to use `checked="0/1"`.

Try this:

```
<tr align="center">
    <td align="center">
        <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="j" value="Pre-Quarantine" <? if ($dato['Status'] == 'Pre-Quaratine'){ echo 'checked'; } ?> /><span>Pre-Quarantine</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="j" value="Quarantine" <? if ($dato['Status'] == 'Quarantine'){ echo 'checked'; } ?> /><span>Quarantine</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="j" value="Released" <? if ($dato['Status'] == 'Released'){ echo 'checked'; } ?> /><span>Released</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Just `checked` is the HTML specification, while `checked="checked"` is the XHTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP opening tag is not correct..it should be `<?php` and not just `<?` unless you have enabled short tags....

Also the value for `checked` attribute is `checked` if it has to be checked..

Replace

```
checked="<? if ($dato['Status'] == 'Pre-Quaratine'){ echo true; } ?>"
```

with

```
checked="<?php if ($dato['Status'] == 'Pre-Quaratine'){ echo 'checked'; } ?>"
```

Comment: Short tags are perfectly acceptable if they are enabled -  `short_open_tag enabled in php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using checked="checked" works best on most browsers.

Answer (score 0):

PHP tags should start with `<?php`, not just `<?`:

```
<tr align="center">
            <td align="center">
                <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="j" value="Pre-Quarantine" checked="<?php if ($dato['Status'] == 'Pre-Quaratine'){ echo true; } ?>"/><span>Pre-Quarantine</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="j" value="Quarantine" checked="<?php if ($dato['Status'] == 'Quarantine'){ echo true; } ?>"/><span>Quarantine</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="j" value="Released" checked="<?php if ($dato['Status'] == 'Released'){ echo true; } ?>"/><span>Released</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to use ternary operators:

And other thing that I noticed is this >

```
value="Pre-Quarantine"
```

Notice de N in Quarantine

and >

```
$dato['Status'] == 'Pre-Quaratine'
```

Notice the misspell en Quaratine Missing the N (is it intentional?)

```
<tr align="center">
    <td align="center">
        <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="j" value="Pre-Quarantine" <?php if ( $dato['Status'] == 'Pre-Quaratine') : ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?>/><span>Pre-Quarantine</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="j" value="Quarantine" <?php if ( $dato['Status'] == 'Quaratine') : ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?>/><span>Quarantine</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <div class="column column2"><label><input type="radio" name="j" value="Released" <?php if ( $dato['Status'] == 'Released') : ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?>/><span>Released</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```